# The decimal is not taken into acount in the equation

Tags: c++, int, decimal, rounding, equation

I've only recently gotten into C++ and I plan on making games mostly. Naturally I decided to play around and see what I could do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main ()
{ 
    int HIT, DMG, HRT, ATK, DEF, EVS, EVS1, CRT, CRT1, CRT2, CRTMUL, CRTMUL1, BK, BKDMG;

    srand( time(0));

    HIT=rand()%100+1;

    cout<<"Please enter thier Evasion: ";
    cin >> EVS;

    EVS1 = 100 - EVS;

    if ( HIT < EVS1 ) {
        cout<<"Hit!";
        cout << '\n';
    }

    else if ( HIT > EVS1 ) {
        cout<<"Miss!";
        return 0;
    }

    cout<<"Please enter your Damage: ";
    cin >> DMG;

    cout<<"Please enter your Attack: ";
    cin >> ATK;

    cout<<"Please enter thier Defence: ";
    cin >> DEF;

    cout<<"Please enter your Crit Chance: ";
    cin >> CRT;

    cout<<"Please enter your Crit Multiplier: ";
    cin >> CRTMUL1;


    CRT1=rand()%100+1;

    CRT2 = 100 - CRT;

    if ( CRT1 < CRT2 ) {
        cout<<"You didnt crit.";
        cout << '\n';
    CRTMUL = 1;
    }

    else if ( CRT1 > CRT2 ) {
        cout<<"Crit!";
        cout << '\n';
        CRTMUL = CRTMUL1;
    }   


    // no matter what you input here,...
    cout<<"From where did you hit them? ";
    cout << '\n';
    cout<<"(1 for from the back, 2 for from the side, 3 for from the front).";
    cout << '\n';
    cin >> BK;
    // ...this area...
    if ( BK = 1 ) {
        BKDMG = 1.6;
    }

    else if ( BK = 2 ) {
        BKDMG = 1.3;
    }

    else if ( BK = 3 ) {
        BKDMG = 1;
    }
    // ... to this area wont work, in the equation below BKDMG is allways 1
    HRT =  ((((((ATK/5)/100)+1)*(DMG))-(((((ATK/5)/100)+1)*(DMG))/100)*(DEF/5))*BKDMG)*CRTMUL;

    cout<<"You hit for ";
    cout<<HRT;
    cout<<" damage!";

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see within the code, no matter what you input for BK it seems that BKDMG will all ways result in 1. I believe this is because of rounding? If not let me know.

If so how do I fix this problem? I think the answer is somewhere on here but I don't know exactly what to search as I don't know exactly what the problem is. From what I can understand float could help me? I don't understand what a float is as this is the first thing I have coded.

Comment: First problem: `if (BK = 1)` doesn't do what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined BKDMG to be of type `int` meaning that it can only hold integers. So, yes, if you assign it a real-number value it will round it down to the next integer value. Using `double` or `float` would probably suffice for this example.

Your conditions are also wrong:

```
if ( BK = 1 ) {
    BKDMG = 1.6;
}
```

Because 'BK = 1' is an assignment, it always sets the value of BK to 1. The code snippet above should be:

```
if ( BK == 1 ) {
    BKDMG = 1.6;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiles, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Chnossos: Because it's assigning a `double` literal to an `int` variable. It's been a while since I've done C or C++, but I'd *expect* that to fail - it certainly would in Java or C#, and I didn't think C++ was quite *that* loose with its typing. But Having just tried it, yes, it does. Wow.

Comment: yeah, compilers in C/C++ are not that strict about numeric types. Simply because sometimes you __want__ that rounding to happen.

Comment: @Chnossos In the case of C++, the reason is more C compatibility.  Sometimes, you do want lossy conversions, but they're not the majority of the time, and when you want them, you can use `static_cast`.  Historically, C silently converts any numeric type into any other, and despite efforts on the part of some to change this, C compatibility has always been invoked to block the change.

Comment: This is why writing if (1 == BK) is safer. If you miss a '=' it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( BK = 1 )
```

Is a classic (beginners) mistake. You are not comparing, you are assigning.

It should be

```
if ( BK == 1 )
```

Or even better,

```
if ( 1 == BK)
```

If you put the constant first, it is impossible to make the error.